# Pass a return value from Oracle Reports to Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oraclereports

**Is it possible** that the Oracle Report will return a value (ex. 1 or 0) to the calling form after it was successfully generated?

Comment: The idea to return the value to the calling form once the report is generated or executed?

Answer (score 0):

If you call the report using HTTP Post/URL method you will not be able to determine if it completed successfully.

You can submit the report to the report server and then poll for report status.  Then launch the report if it ran successfully or log the error if it failed.